# Is there a way to find and change Facebook account's privacy settings programmatically?

Tags: android, objective-c, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know if it is possible to find and manage privacy settings for a Facebook account programmatically. Like Jumbo Privacy app is doing.

I'm trying to find out if there is a way possible to change the privacy settings like timeline and tagging and a post's privacy settings, and friend-list's privacy settings (who can view my friend-list), programmatically using android or swift.

I've also seen an app named Jumbo Privacy app which is able to change privacy settings of an account. I just want to know if there is a pathway given by Facebook to do so or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this via any of the official APIs provided by Facebook.

If you got any app or service doing this, then they presumably must be doing it in some way that is explicitly not allowed, such as interacting with the web UI directly, or mimicking internal API calls, that were not meant for public consumption.